# How to turn on the Wi-Fi Power in a UWP app?

Tags: wifi, uwp

I want turn on the Wi-Fi Power in my uwp application. 
How to turn on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general UWP applications don't have access to change global settings or settings that may interfere with other running applications. If you want to detect the status of the network you can do that with the class [NetworkInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452991.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Control of the devices radios is available to the OEM and carriers but is not available to other developers.

That said, for those that do have access the [WiFiAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.aspx) class allows for all the WiFi adapters in the device to be enumerated and programmatically connected or disconnected. The adapters are enumerated with [FindAllAdaptersAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.findalladaptersasync.aspx). Calling this method requires the wifiControl capability. There are some other radio related capabilities in the namespace [Windows.Devices.Radios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn996447).

Access to some APIs is restricted depending on the account type that you are using for development. For more information see Microsoft's [documentation on Account Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/account-types-locations-and-fees).

Answer (score 3):

On UWP, You should **ask users** to enable WiFi. or any other device.
Best practice is to navigate them to the WiFi settings to turn it on, via a [URI Launcehr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx).

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:network-wifi"));
```

If the WiFi is enabled, then you can access it from `Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter`.

But before that you have to add the required device capability to the **Package.appxmanifest** file - Right Click on the file -> Open with -> XML (Text) Editor) and adding the device capability below:

```
<Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <!-- Add the capability here -->
    <DeviceCapability Name="wifiControl" />
</Capabilities>
```

Then you can access the WiFi adapter programmatically like this:

```
var access = await Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
if(access == Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    var result = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
        Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
    if(result.Count >= 1)
    {
        Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter firstAdapter = 
            await Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync(result[0].Id);
        await firstAdapter.ScanAsync();
    }
}
```

More: [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/wificonnectsample).

Comment: solved my problem. DeviceCapability was just missing.

Comment: @Ammar Glad it did.